# Unable to frame sql query correctly from java

Tags: sql, string, hibernate, postgresql, double-quotes

I am trying to query data from my app, through postgresql DB. What I want to achieve is **from "Users" where "Username"='stackoverflow'**

If this query is written in the SQl editor and run, it gives the expected result.

Thus, am trying to send the query in the same format, as

`String SQL_QUERY = "from " + "\"Users\"" + " where "
                    + "Username" + "=" + "'"
                    + request.getParameter("username") + "'";`

When I run this, I get the following error: 
**unexpected char: '"' [from "Users" where Username=user1]**

If I remove the double quotes, it wont work, saying table named users doesn't exist. 
What is the way out of this deadlock? Where am I going wrong ??

Thank you.

Comment: Its not compulsory. It can be framed without select *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the Postgresql syntax has in the end helped in getting a solution. Changed all the column names to small capitals and then tried, which solved most of the problems. Thanks to A.H

```
        String SQL_QUERY = "FROM Users WHERE username ='" + username + "'";
        Query query = objSession.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);

        List list = query.list();
        for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Users objUsers = (Users) it.next();
            System.out.println("Username: " + objUsers.userName);
            System.out.println("Password: " + objUsers.password);
            System.out.println("Name: " + objUsers.name);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you want:

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String SQL_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM \"Users\" WHERE \"Username\" ='" + username + "'";
```

You can check this by

```
System.out.println(SQL_QUERY);
```

which prints

```
SELECT * FROM "Users" WHERE "Username" ='foo'
```

**ATTENTION/DANGER**: This statement will solve your problem with the PostgreSQL mixed-case tablename and columnnames. **BUT** providing the value for `Username` to the query this way makes you vulnerable to even the easiest [SQL-Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack. Please use `PreparedStatement` instead and write

```
String SQL_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM \"Users\" WHERE \"Username\" = ?";
```

Comment: Error:  SQL_QUERY-->SELECT * FROM "Users" WHERE "Username" ='user1'
Feb 12, 2012 2:11:46 AM org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
SEVERE: *** ERROR: line 1:8: unexpected token: *
unexpected char: '"' [SELECT * FROM "Users" WHERE "Username" ='user1']

Comment: Withough select *, error: SQL_QUERY-->FROM "Users" WHERE "Username" ='user1'
unexpected char: '"' [FROM "Users" WHERE "Username" ='user1']

Comment: The `hibernate` part tells me, that you are _not_ using SQL. This would also explain the missing `SELECT ...` part. Right?

Comment: Its HSQL that am using. Hibernate SQL

Comment: HSQL is _not_ SQL, it is _translated_ into SQL and has its completely own syntax. So... Do you have any mapping files (`*.hbm.xml`) or using any annotations to do the mappings? If so, edit your question by showing them and by bringing Hibernate officially into the game.

Comment: Fine. Will try with the POJO's

Comment: Afterthough: Do _really_ mean HSQL or HQL instead?

Comment: It doesn't work even on using POJO's calsses. Same cases as with the query. Sorry, I meant HQL.

Comment: If you are really using POJOs (i.e. a class `Users` without _any_ annotations) then there must be some XML configuration files. Please show them to us.

Comment: List results = objSession.createQuery(
     "from " + "\"Users\"" + " objUsers where objUsers.name='"
       + username + "'").list();

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7568/discussion-between-ajj-and-a-h)

Answer (score 0):

Where's the `SELECT` clause of the query? It needs to be something like this:

`String SQL_QUERY= "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='" + request.getParameter("username") + "'";`

Or like this:

`String SQL_QUERY= "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Users WHERE Username='" + request.getParameter("username") + "'";`

Here's a very similar example that uses PreparedStatement to avoid a SQL injection security attack: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java

Comment: Even specifying all columns rather than * ain't helping.

Comment: Error which i face when I frame wuery as u have suggested. :: SEVERE: ERROR: relation "users" does not exist
  Position: 126
could not execute query

Comment: If I give double quotes to "Users" then I get the error:: unexpected char: '"' [from "Users"where Username = 'user1'].                 Am confused on how to proceed on executing this query.

Comment: Using `createNativeQuery()` instead of `createQuery()` fixed it for me